# Cannot access html variables inside javascript in AEM

Tags: javascript, aem

I was trying to make a form which takes name and email as input. Clicking the submit button it should display an alert box saying "Thank You *name*".

I know how to access input variables from HTML by setting an Id and access them inside script tag, but things are trouble in AEM. Here is my code

```
<sly data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}">
    <span>${component.title}</span>
</sly>

<div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <div>
        <label>${properties.namelabel}</label>
        <input
            type="${properties.inputType}"
            name="${properties.name}"
            placeholder="${properties.placeholder}"
            required="${properties.required && 'required'}"
            />
    </div>
     <div>
         <label>${properties.maillabel}</label>
         <input
            type="${properties.einputType}"
            name="${properties.ename}"
            placeholder="${properties.eplaceholder}"
            required="${properties.required && 'required'}"
           />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type = "button" onclick="myFunction();">

            ${properties.buttlabel}

        </button>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Thank You");
}
</script>
```

If I set Id inside the input tag, how can I particularly access the name variable inside Javascript?

Comment: `$('input')[0].attr('name')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the comment reply and the other answer didn't solve my problem. After trying with some jquery/JS combinations, I could make it work by adding an id selector in the input tag :

```
 <input id = "abc"
     type="${properties.inputType}"
     name="${properties.name}"
     placeholder="${properties.placeholder}"
     required="${properties.required && 'required'}"
  />
```

Got the namevalue from the id inside the script tag :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

var nameValue = document.getElementById("abc").value;
  alert("Thank You" + nameValue);
}
</script>
```